# Dynamic filter crosstalk-linked plotly based on DT search

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-markdown, dt

I have data that combines text and scores. I would like to render an HTML file with client-side dynamic text search connected to a plotly scatter plot.

Currently, clicking on one or more point(s) in the plot will display the relevant row(s) in the DT. But going the other way, by selecting rows or searching for phrases in the DT table, does not change the highlighted points in the plot. Ideally, if we search for a phrase (e.g. "Obama") in the DT table, the related points would immediately be highlighted. Is there some way to do that?

Alternatively, should I use `filter_select` from `crosstalk` or a `plotly` option to make it possible to filter points based on the appearance of target text in the `sentence` field?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r }
library(tidyverse)
library(crosstalk)
library(plotly)
set.seed(0)
n = 20
survey <- data.frame(id = 1:n,
                     date = as.Date("2023-01-01") + runif(n = n, max = 100),
                     score = sample(0:10, n, replace = TRUE),
                     sentence = wakefield::sentence(n = n) |> str_wrap(40))

survey_shared <- SharedData$new(survey, key = ~id)

p <- ggplot(survey_shared, aes(date, score, text = sentence)) +
  geom_point()

ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text") %>% layout(hoverlabel = list(align = "left")) 

DT::datatable(survey_shared, rownames = FALSE, width = "100%")

```
````

[image]

Comment: Does my below approach work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not (yet) sure why, but it works once you remove the `key` from your `SharedData$new` call (`row.names` are used by default).

**Edit:** `datatable` seems to expect a character key. Using `id = as.character(1:n)` when defining the `data.frame` makes your initial code functional.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r }
library(tidyverse)
library(crosstalk)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

set.seed(0)
n = 20
survey <- data.frame(id = 1:n,
                     date = as.Date("2023-01-01") + runif(n = n, max = 100),
                     score = sample(0:10, n, replace = TRUE),
                     sentence = wakefield::sentence(n = n) |> str_wrap(40))

survey_shared <- SharedData$new(survey)

p <- ggplot(survey_shared, aes(date, score, text = sentence)) +
  geom_point()

ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text") %>% layout(hoverlabel = list(align = "left")) %>% highlight(on = "plotly_click", off = "plotly_doubleclick") %>% highlight(on = "plotly_selected", off = "plotly_deselect") # for lasso and box select
DT::datatable(survey_shared, rownames = FALSE, width = "100%")

```
````

Comment: This gets me a little closer, but  I'm still wondering how to make searching for phrases in the DT table change the highlighted points in the plot. "Ideally, if we search for a phrase (e.g. "Obama") in the DT table, the related points would immediately be highlighted. Is there some way to do that?"

Comment: In a `shiny` context I'd use `dataTableProxy` along with `selectRows()` once `input$mytable_search` is triggered. Without shiny you'll need a JS callback selecting all available rows after searching. Maybe you'll find some inspiration [here](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DTcallbacks.html#select-rows-on-click-and-drag).